# Binning via `geom_hex` an `geom_bin_2d` produce conflicting plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, binning

I am trying to use binning to deal with overplotting with `geom_hex` an `geom_bin_2d`.

But I am getting conflicting plots with different areas of the plot showing more counts.

I understand that the binning by these two methods are different, but why are the plots so different ? How can I get more standardized plots for both so that the interpretation is not messed up?

### Example 1

```
library(ggplot2)
bks = seq(from = 0, to = 10000, by = 1000)
d <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat, price))
d + geom_point(alpha = 0.01)
```

[image]

```
d + geom_hex(bins = 40) + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", breaks = bks)
d + geom_bin_2d(bins = 40) + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", breaks = bks)
```

[image]

```
d + geom_hex() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", limits = c(0, 6000))
d + geom_bin_2d() + scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red", limits = c(0, 6000))
```

[image]

### Example 2

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgbif)
library(maps)

# get gbif data
gdata <- occ_data(scientificName = "Aix sponsa", country = "US", 
                  year="2020", limit = 5000)
gdata <- gdata$data

# prepare map
usa <- sf::st_as_sf(map('usa', plot = FALSE, fill = TRUE))
usa <- sf::st_transform(usa, sp::CRS("+init=epsg:4326"))

ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = usa)


# Convert occurence data to sf
gdata_sf <- st_as_sf(gdata, coords = c('decimalLongitude', 'decimalLatitude'),
                     crs = st_crs(usa))

# Plot points
ggplot(usa) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = gdata_sf, alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

```
bks = seq(from = 0, to = 200, by = 50)

ggplot(usa) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_bin_2d(data = gdata, aes(x = decimalLongitude, y = decimalLatitude,
                                fill = after_stat(count)),
              alpha = 0.8, colour = "white", bins = 40) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", limits = c(0, 200)) +
  geom_sf(data = gdata_sf, alpha = 0.1) + 
  theme_void()


ggplot(usa) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_hex(data = gdata, aes(x = decimalLongitude, y = decimalLatitude,
                             fill = after_stat(count)),
           alpha = 0.8, colour = "white", bins = 40) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", limits = c(0, 200)) +
  geom_sf(data = gdata_sf, alpha = 0.1) +
  theme_void()
```

[image]

Comment: I have copy and pasted your code and can't reproduce your hex figures from example 1. Mine look very similar to your bin2d version. I'm using ggplot2_3.3.6 on windows.

Comment: Looks fine for me too with ggplot2 3.3.5 on Linux.